# Pygame problem: how to make an object disappear after collision and create a new object over and over?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I am trying to create a game that places a cat which I can move left and right at the bottom of the screen.

Then I make a ball appear at a random position on the top of the screen and fall down the screen at a steady rate.

If the cat catches the ball by colliding with it, I make the ball disappear.

Meanwhile, I make a new ball each time the cat catches the ball or whenever the ball disappears off the bottom of the screen.

My question is: how do I make the ball disappear after being caught by the cat and then create a new ball over and over?

Currently I can think of two approaches to this problem:

First, I create a single ball. Once the cat catches the ball, I write some codes to make THAT ball disappear. Then, write some codes to create a new ball. Put these codes in a loop somehow to keep a ball disappear and reappear over and over. The problem is, I am not sure which codes to write to make a ball disappear and then create a new one.

Second approach is, I create a group of balls `balls = Group()` using pygame.sprite. I let those balls drop one after another.  When a cat catches a ball, I remove that ball from the group of balls. Then let another ball in the group drop.

```
for ball in balls.copy():
    if cat.rect.colliderect(ball.rect):
        balls.remove(ball)
```

This second approach has somehow created another problem. When I wanted to specify the collision between the cat and each ball, I sometimes received the error message saying that either the name "ball" is not define or the name "balls" is not defined. Plus, I don't know whether it is really necessary to use a for loop whenever I want to specify a cat-ball collision. I feel that there has to be a more straight-forward and efficient way than this.

Would the first approach be better? If yes, please let me know how to make a ball disappear and to create a new ball immediately afterwards. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Why not just use one ball, and when the cat "catches" it, move it back to the top of the screen?

Comment: You are doing it the way I would recommend with Sprites and Sprite groups. Can you include a traceback of the actual errors you are getting and include the code for that so it is possible to help you see what is going on with those variables?
I would use `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`, instead of the for loop you have shown in your question. `spritecollide()` will return a list of the colliding sprites (in this case a list with a single entry - the ball the cat caught) and then you can call `remove()` on the returned list

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to create a sprite with the following template:

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ falls and restarts the ball position when ball hits the cat or the ground"""

    def __init__(self):
        """ setting up the ball image, rect, caught_by_cat flag etc. """

    def update(self):
        if self.hits_the_ground():
            self.reset()
        elif self.caught_by_cat:
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.fall()

    def reset(self):
        """ randomize the ball position and set the ball rect to this position and resets the caught_by_cat flag """

    def hits_the_ground(self):
        """ checks whether ball hits the bottom of the board """

    def fall(self):
        """ move the ball rectangle with a steady speed """
```

and then after the initialization and adding it to the `pygame.sprite.Group`, in the game event loop simply:

1. `sprite_group.update()`
2. `sprite_group.draw(screen)`
3. Check for collision

```
if cat_collides_with_ball:
        ball.caught_by_cat = True
```

This way you don't need to create many ball objects, you just need to restart the ball `rect` attribute to draw it in other place.